# Получить root path Java (Spring MVC)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Мне в крон-методе необходимо получить рутовый путь.
Ранее, в контроллерах, я использовать UriComponentBuilder, но в кроны лежат в сервисах и никакой связи с контроллером не имеют.

Цель: надо сформировать линку для письма, которое отправляется по крону, чтобы пользователь сразу мог перейти на страницу профиля.

Как можно это сделать? Многое что перепробовал и все возвращает нуль на объектах.

Comment: У вас нет request объекта и поэтому не откуда взять путь.

Comment: requet не нужен. Нужен `ServletContext`. Можно ли его получить в кроне? Если не ошибаюсь, крон тоже выполняется в этом контексте, ибо он и представляет собой web-приложение (`There is one context per "web application" per Java Virtual Machine.`). Наверняка должен быть способ.

Answer (score 0):

Заинъекти [WebApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html) в свой крон. В нём есть метод [getServletContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html#getServletContext--). Но сразу оговорюсь, что домен ты никак не получишь, его можно стянуть только из **http**-заголовка **Host** входящего запроса.